# Output of empty columns in streamlit aggrid shown as "None" or <NA>

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit

since I need to share my results to non-coders in order to make their lives easier, I found the streamlit package for python, which seems to be pretty user-friendly on first view. I am already testing it for few days and found a challenge, which I thought is easy to solve

**Challenge**: I have following testframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import AgGrid

testFrame=pd.DataFrame({"col1":[np.nan,1,2,4],"col2":[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
grid_return=AgGrid(testFrame, editable=True)
General=grid_return["data"]
new_df=General
st.write(new_df)
```

My goal is to use the AGrid library to manipulate the data in real-time and at a later step to save them as an excel. The output, however contains artefacts, I dont want to have, since in a later step I am saving the file as excel, and having them is not nice

```
col1         col2
<NA>         <NA>
1.0000       <NA>
2.0000       <NA>
4.0000       <NA>
```

I tried to use the command

```
new_df=new_df.replace("<NA">,"",regex=True)
```

but this does not work. I also tried some different things, but no success. Any suggestion?

Any support is more than appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I did find a work-around, hoping if someone might have the same issue will find this useful.

The issue I am facing is that I read an excel file, and the moment I change data in the application I get "None" or "". My solution is the following

```
df=pd.read_excel(path)
df.fillna(" ",inplace=True) ## this is the work-around: Replace empty cells with " "
grid_return=AgGrid(df, editable=True)
df=grid_return["data"]
df.replace(" ","",inplace=True)  ##replace the " " with ""
```

This works and I can save the excel file without an issue. If someone might have a better and more comfortable solution please let me know :)